# Visual Studio debugging tests takes a really long time to update variable values

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

I'm having an issue with my Visual Studio 2022 installation where frequently it takes an incredibly long time for it to start fully working during debugging.  This seems to mostly occur when debugging unit tests but I have seen it trying to debug other situations.

What happens is I will start the debugger, a break point will be hit. From there if I try to mouse over a variable nothing happens. If I try to step through the code it seems like it does step, but the highlighted line and marker on the left hand side of the text editor do not update.

It can take anywhere from 10 second to even a few minutes for it to start behaving as expected. I've Googled around on my issue and haven't found any helpful tips. I've updated my installation, I've cleared my cache at %USERDATA%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\your version xxx\ComponentModelCache. I'm uncertain what else to try.

Does anyone have any ideas for what I could try to fix this? I'm at my wits end with how slow this is!

Update as of 2024-01-05. I haven't seemed to encounter this issue lately. I'm uncertain if it's related to the project I was working on or not or whether a Visual Studio update fixed it. I haven't experienced the issue lately which seems to suggest it's project-related as I'm not experiencing it in the projects I am working on more frequently now. Sorry I don't have a better resolution for anyone who may be experiencing a similar issue.

Comment: Do you have a virus checker?  Check Task Manager and see available memory and Processor Usage.

Comment: @jdweng, no antivirus software besides the Windows Defender. When the debugger is lagging there is no noticeable increase in Visual Studio processor or memory usage.

Comment: Try clearing all of the existing debugger breakpoints, exception settings, and watches.  Then add the line breakpoint back.

Comment: Looks like you can exclude Defender check VS.  See : https://blog.peterritchie.com/posts/visual-studio-defender-performance

Comment: any update of this issue?

Comment: @BowmanZhu-MSFT no, no luck yet. It seems like if I close out my Visual Studio when this starts happening and then reopen the issue gets better.

Answer (score 1):

IDE build processes may be impacted by antivirus software real-time protection. It may or may not be the issue here; I guess it could be worth trying to ***temporarily*** de-activate real-time protection to see if this is indeed the culprit.

1. Press the "Windows" key
2. Type "`Windows Security`"
3. Select "`Virus & Threat Protection`"
4. Under "`Virus & Threat Protection settings`" select "`Manage settings`"
5. Under "`Real-time protection`", set the toggle from "`On`" to "`Off`"

Try debugging in Visual Studio and see if the issue has been solved. It may be worth re-booting your machine beforehand to ensure that the antivirus settings have been applied.

Whether the issue has been solved or not, for security reasons it is very important to go back to "`Real-time protection`" in your settings and turn it back "`On`" after you're done testing.

If the issue was indeed solved by turning off "`Real-time protection`", then you would have to look into excluding the specific directories used by Visual Studio from Windows Defender real-time protection features. This can be done in multiple ways. There are many guides and even some automated scripts online; here are a few of them:

Script:
https://gist.github.com/Braytiner/be2497d1a06f5a9d943dc7760693d460

Guide:
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006298560

Note that the guide is for another IDE, but the advice offered therein can be applied to Visual Studio with minor changes.

If real-time protection is not the issue, unfortunately more troubleshooting is necessary to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please try creating a new solution, and check whether the issue can be reproduced in the new solution.

If the issue can be reproduced, please share the detailed reproduction steps.

If the issue is unable to reproduce in the new solution, you could try to remove the .vs folder in the old solution, because intellisence info is in that folder. After that, remove all breakpoints and add them all again. If the issue still exists, you could reset the vs settings.

By the way, you could run 'devenv /safemode' to make sure this situation is not caused by extensions.

Comment: I'm not OP, but have the same issue. Removing the .vs folder and removing all breakpoints didn't work and I'm not able to run the project with /safemode. I was not able to reproduce the issue on a new solution with minimal code. Let me know if you have any ideas on how to troubleshoot this further.

Comment: I think I replied to the same person on my root post, but the issue appears to resolve itself by restarting visual studio when it happens. I have already tried  clearing watches and breakpoints, I haven't tried nuking the .vs folder yet but I'll give that a try and see if that helps it things.

Comment: @Zulukas Hi, if you find a solution to narrow down this issue, you could post an answer and [mark it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question, this will be helpful to others who encountered this issue. :)